# Phone and Email Validation in Java

Tags: java, validation

I am relatively new to Java and I am making a Login form with details such as email and phone number. I was wondering how to validate if an email and phone number is valid? For example, an email must have an “@“ and a domain. And a phone number must be 11 digits long. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: no doubt plenty of libraries that do that. Have you tried googling?

Comment: This sounds more like "how do I learn about basic String techniques" question rather than a "how do I professionally validate data". The answer to the first one is "look around", the internet is filled with beginner code like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Email Verfication**

1. You can use regex matching to validate that the email is correct.

```
    emailAddress = "username+something@domain.com";
    regexPattern = "^(?=.{1,64}@)[A-Za-z0-9\\+_-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\+_-]+)*@" 
        + "[^-][A-Za-z0-9\\+-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\+-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    assertTrue(EmailValidation.patternMatches(emailAddress, regexPattern));
```

2. You can use the apache-commons library to test the email address

```
    emailAddress = "username@domain.com";
    assertTrue(EmailValidator.getInstance()
      .isValid(emailAddress));
```

**Phone Number**

1. If the phone number is simple 10 digit number then you can use the regex `"^\\d{10}$"`
2. You can use `libphonenumber` library by google.

**References**

1. https://www.baeldung.com/java-email-validation-regex
2. https://www.baeldung.com/java-regex-validate-phone-numbers